# IAM role token refresh for long-running Spark job

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-s3, pyspark, aws-java-sdk

I am running Apache Spark in an EKS cluster. I'm using IAM Roles for ServiceAccounts (IRSA) to attach IAM permissions to the Spark pods. In order to use the role permissions I have to set the following in my PySpark context:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('My Project')\
    .config("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.aws.credentials.provider", "com.amazonaws.auth.WebIdentityTokenCredentialsProvider") \
    .config("spark.kubernetes.namespace", "my-namespace") \
    .config("spark.kubernetes.authenticate.driver.serviceAccountName", "my-service-account-name") \
    .config("spark.kubernetes.authenticate.submission.caCertFile", "/var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/ca.crt") \
    .config("spark.kubernetes.authenticate.submission.oauthTokenFile", "/var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token") \
    .getOrCreate()
```

This works, but after 60 minutes of a long-running job that interacts with S3 I get this error:

```
com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: The provided token has expired. (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ExpiredToken;
```

Is there any solution to this other than increasing the maximum session duration on my IAM role? If my understanding is correct, IRSA should automatically refresh the token in the `oauthTokenFile` path, but Spark must have the old token loaded into memory and is continuing to use it or something.